# If checkbox is checked - show input field. Works in JSFiddle, not on website

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I probably have been staring at this too long and am missing something obvious, but: why is this working fine in JSFiddle and NOT when I upload it??

The alert at the end is showing up on the test website, but the "showthis" is also visible no matter what.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Form Field</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/showfield.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="checkbox" />
<br />
<input id="showthis" name="showthis" size="50" type="text" value="text here"/>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery (I've downloaded a minified jQuery 1.11.0 , which is what's working in JSFiddle)

```
//hide field by default
$('input[name="showthis"]').hide();

//show it when the checkbox is clicked
$('input[name="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
    $('input[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
} 
else {
    $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
}
});


// the alert is showing fine 
alert ("hello");
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DLQY9/

Comment: did you add teh script in a dom ready handler

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your code in a loading event. This is the newer, preferred, syntax (rather than `$(window)` or `$(document)`):

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();

    //show it when the checkbox is clicked
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('input[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/DLQY9/1/

Comment: Thank you! This is working perfectly . (and apparently I need 4 more points in order to be able to upvote)

Comment: I doing this is a form and hiding the fields work, but when submit is press it does not send the data of the previously hidden fields. Anyone can shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('input[name="showthis"]').hide();

//show it when the checkbox is clicked
$('input[name="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
    $('input[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
} 
else {
    $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good but there is a little problem in them. If you refresh page when `checkbox` checked, `showthis` will be hide because of first line :

```
$('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
```

So we need another condition before on click listener as follow :

```
$(function () {
    if($('input[name="checkbox"]').prop('checked')){
        $('input[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
    }

    //show it when the checkbox is clicked
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('input[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('input[name="showthis"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```